# Track call to MVC action when page is loaded in Facebook preview

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have an ASP.Net MVC web application. When I share a url of the application to Facebook, it will make a call and show the website preview.

Is it possible to track this call to action from my application.

I used Request.UrlReferrer, but I cannot track the call from Facebook.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who meets with this requirement, following is how I solved this issue. Thanks to @cbroe for giving me the idea of handling the calls with url.

I used UrlReferrer of Request to get the calling url.

```
if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{                         
     if(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().ToLower().Contains("facebook"))
     {
          /*Call came from Facebook.
          * This can wither be from the website preview generated
          * when we first post the url in Facebook, or calls received
          * at any further period */
     }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the Facebook scraper by the User-Agent request header it sends.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1748179212062572

Comment: Actually I solved the issue using UrlReferrer. Thanks got the idea of taking the calling url from your answer.